# How to embed a quicktab instance in a page?

Tags: 7, blocks

How do I can embed a qiucktab instance in page? I'm not going to create a region and assign the quicktab into that region. is there anyway to do such thing without using region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [QuickTabs Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs_field_collection) module. Module page says :

> The Quick Tabs Field Collection module provides a field formatter for
>   rendering field collections as Quick Tabs.

**Usage :**

> 1. Go to the Manage Display page for any Entity that contains a field-collection field.
> 2. Change the formatter to QuickTabs
> 3. Click the gear icon on the right to access the formatter settings.
>
>    (REQUIRED) Enter the machine-name of the field to use for the tab values.
>
>    (REQUIRED) Enter the machine-name of the field to use for the tab contents.
>
>    Optionally tick the box to strip all HTML tags from the tab content.
>
>    Optionally add custom classes that will output in the field-collection wrapper div.
>
>    Optionally configure the available QuickTabs options.
> 4. Adjust formatter settings for each of the fields in the field-collection.

Answer (score 3):

After creating the quicktabs, you can render the quicktab programatically from the template file of that page.

Please put the below code inside your template file:

```
  $quicktabs = quicktabs_build_quicktabs('myquicktab');
  print render($quicktabs);
```